# How to add data-attribute to the form tag in simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, custom-data-attribute

I'm using garlic.js to validate my forms. Garlic.js recommends adding a **data-attribute** on the **form tag**.

Here's what I need to generate:

```
<form data-validate="parsley">
```

I'm having issues to generate this data attribute on the form tag. I tried everything and nothing worked. Anyone has a solution to this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @entity, :html => {:"data-validate" => 'parsley'} do |f| %>
    <!-- inputs -->
<% end %>
```

**Update**

From the comment below, to have the form include an HTML5 data attribute with no value try the following:

```
<%= simple_form_for @entity, :html => {:"other-data-value" => ''} do |f| %>
```

By setting the attribute to an empty string the form helper renders just the attribute.

Comment: what to do if the data attribute does not need a value? just data-validate? I tried with data-validate: true but it din not work out

Comment: @VysakhSreenivasan I updated the answer to show how what you are asking can be accomplished. Hope that helps!

Comment: I do a little bit different. Add ```input_html: { data: { validate: "required"} }``` in every input field. Ex: ```f.input :title, label: false, input_html: { data: { validate: "required" }, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Post Title" }```

Answer (score 3):

You can set data attributes directly by passing in a data hash, but all other HTML options must be wrapped in the HTML key. Example:

```
<%= form_for(@post, data: { validate: "parsley" }, html: { name: "go" }) do |f| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

The HTML generated for this would be:

```
<form action='http://www.example.com' method='post' data-validate='parsley' name='go'>
  ...
 </form>
```

[api.rubyonrails.org](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)

Comment: This is the only one that worked. I didn't know about the `data:` wrapper, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this in 2016 using either the newer version of Rails (4) or the newer version of Parsley (2) here is what you'll need to do:

First of all to activate parsley with data attributes in the new version you add `data-parsley-validate` now instead of the `data-validate="parsley"` from version 1 of Parsley. Now lets get that to work with rails `form_for`.

Even if you're not using parsley, this is how to insert a data attribute in Rails 4.

```
<%= form_tag '/login', :"data-parsley-validate" => '' do %>
    <!-- inputs -->
<% end %>
```

So basically the difference is not using the `html=>{}` hash. I tried that to see if that trick would work and at least for me my markup looked like this:

```
<form action="/login" method="post" html="{:data-parsley-validate}">
    <!-- inputs -->
</form>
```

But by simply putting the data attribute directly in there as a symbol with an empty string as the corresponding value and it worked perfectly. This is the markup I received.

```
<form action="/login" method="post" data-parsley-validate>
    <!-- inputs -->
</form>
```

In other words its perfect. So thats how to use Rails 4 to get data attributes in your `form_tag`.